# Condition based where in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

```
$input = Input::all();

$state_name = (empty($input['state_name'])?'':$input['state_name']);
$score = (empty($input['score'])?'':$input['score']);

$GetUsersList = User::CheckForActive();

if($state_name!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('state_name'.$state_name);

if($score!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('score'.'<'.$score)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get();
```

Hello,

Above is my code of `UserController` I want to get records of `user table` based on condition. But every time it returns nothing. If I removed `if` conditions then it works fine. But in my case its not necessary that every time `state_name` and `score` will passed. That's why i have put `if` conditions.

Comment: Does it typo or mistake in your where clause.

Comment: Did you try to do your request with SQL to test the validity of your request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `orderBy` and `->get()` inside second if condition, you will get result only when there is `$score!=''` so change your code like

```
$GetUsersList = User::CheckForActive();

if($state_name!=''){
     $GetUsersList->where('state_name', $state_name);
}

if($score!=''){
     $GetUsersList->where('score', '<', $score);
}

$users = $GetUsersList->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Now, you will get result accordingly.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your `where()` methods have the wrong syntax. Use commas, not a chained string.

`->where('state_name', $state_name);`

`->where('score', '<', $score);`

Comment: yeah , you are right. But my issue was not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
if($state_name!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('state_name',$state_name);

if($score!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('score'.'<'.$score)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get();
```

OR

```
if($state_name!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('state_name',$state_name)
                   ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get();

if($score!='')
     $GetUsersList->where('score'.'<'.$score)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->get();
```

Hope this work for you !!